# cant understand how to use url-scheme

Tags: swift, url, instagram, instagram-api, url-scheme

I made authorization with instagram in safari then opens my redirect-URL: “https://badyi.github.io + code “. 
I need to grab redirect-URL. What is url-scheme here?
What is identifier? 
What i have to put in info: URL-types?

I know about canOpenUrl method, but idk what to put in info

For example:
bundleID: 999
clientID: G0G
Secret: 666W
redirect_URL : https://badyi.github.io

Upd:
I use oauth2 to use instagram profile data in my ios app.
what I got:
1) the application opens
2) by clicking on the button, opening the safari with the authorization page
3) after logging in, redirect_url opens in safari

I expect that after 3 steps I will be transferred to my application and I will be able to handle my redirect url

Comment: I suggest you explain what you actually want to achieve, because I don't have the slightest clue. Like "if the user does X, then what happens is Y".

Comment: @gnasher729 updated

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect url has scheme `https`. It means open "in web", that's why it was handled by Safari

If you want to return to your app after auth, you need to implement your own scheme

Please check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) about this feature

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Deeplinks**

As @viktor mentioned, you need to implement your own scheme in your application, and set redirect_URL to it.

For example, if you have application named "FooBar", you can make scheme `foobar`, so the redirect_url can be something like:
`foobar://returnFromRedirect?maybeArg=some`, then, you need to parse this URL in your application and proceed it properly. [Here an article about it](https://www.donnywals.com/handling-deeplinks-in-your-app/)

**Option 2: Universal Links**

You can add `trusted` domain to your application, so all links from this domain can be opened with your application. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)